# JAVA - Representing Month and Year

Tags: java, sql, date

I have an entity and an object, called task, which is related to a reference month and year

```
 public class Task{

        private Long id;
        private Integer referenceMonth;
        private Integer referenceYear;

        .....

 }
```

The task is related, by requirement, to a month and year (but does not need to be accomplished during that month, it is not a due date, it is simply a reference relation).

In the GUI the fields may be represented with a month Datapicker, or with normal input fields with validation.

I normally represent this, both in my classes both in DB as two integer fields.

I'm curios to know which one is considered the most correct and useful representation.

Possibilities.

1- one unique Date field, lets say representing the first day of the reference month, i.e. 01/01/2016

2- A numeric field for year and a field for month

3- A numeric field of the format YYYYMM

4- A mixed representation, one for the DB and one for java

I normally use the #2, i've seen the #3 is very userful for ordering and searches. I note that maybe the less confortable to use for me is the #1, even if it is -maybe- the most formally correct. I never use the #4 as i prefer that java and db are represented the same way.

Some - but not all - aspects to consider:

- formal correctness
- easyness of use
- easyness to query/order by in DB
- easyness to filter in GUI

Which is the most correct and the best solution, for different aspects in your opinion or the one which should be used ?

Note that:
- the question is related BOTH to class design, both to DB design
- for the class design it is constrained to java < 8

Comment: I think your question is a mixture of unclear and too broad. Can you somehow improve it so that there is a clear problem statement that someone can answer *correctly*?

Comment: 5- Java since ver 8 has java.time.YearMonth class

Comment: Unfortunately i need  java < 8 ..

Comment: @Gendarme hope now it's clearer

Comment: Pre-8 high quality design date solution is joda datetime. Has good perception in market, support in few database libraries too (seems better than date v8). Almost all Java8 ideas was battle tested in Joda. What DB layer do You use?

Comment: *"Which is the most correct and the best solution?"* None of them are more *correct* than others. You choose whichever suits you the best. Voting to close as *primarily opinion-based*.

Comment: @JacekCz The Joda-Time project is in maintenance mode, and advises migration to the java.time classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted to Android in the ThreeTenABP project.

Comment: *"Some - but not all - aspects to consider:"* ... While it is true that any given problem typically has a solution that is more elegant than others, it is also true that no particular solution is equally apt for all given problems.  Since we don't know very much about the problem you want to solve, what your use cases are, etc., it is really impossible to generalize meaningfully about "the best solution" ... because there probably isn't one for a general case.

Answer (score 1):

## ISO 8601

When serializing out to a string, and for the database, use standard ISO 8601 format: YYYY-MM

> 2016-12

These standard formats are easy to read, unambiguous, intuitive across cultures, and and sort alphabetically as chronological.

## `YearMonth`

The java.time classes include the [`java.time.YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html). Fit for your purpose.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2016 , 12 );
```

Or, using the handy `Month` enum.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2016 , Month.DECEMBER );
```

Use these objects in your code rather than numbers or strings to provide type-safety, ensure valid values, and make your code more self-documenting.

```
public class Task{
    private Long id;
    private YearMonth referenceYearMonth;
    …
}
```

To generate a String in ISO 8601 format, call `toString`.

```
String output = ym.toString();
```

The class can parse that string.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse( "2016-12" );
```

## Data-entry

For entering data, don't abuse the wrong widget. If you do not have a year-month picker widget, make one such as a wheel for year and a wheel for month. Or allow typing into a pair of text fields.

To populate such fields, interrogate the YearMonth for the year and month.

```
Integer year = ym.getYear();
Integer month = ym.getMonthValue();
```

You can ask the `Month` enum for a localized name of month.

```
String monthName = 
    ym.getMonth().getDisplayName( 
        TextStyle.FULL , 
        Locale.CANADA_FRENCH  );
```

For heavy-duty data entry such as bookkeepers, consider a single field for the user to type the ISO 8601 format.